# how do I download jorte calendar on new tablet

Tags: calendar, jorte

I cant download my jorte calendar from my htc phone to my new tablet becuz the port to recharge my phone is faulty and so the battery keeps dying and wont hold a charge and according to the sprint store, that is the same port that connects my phone and tablet, so therefore I cant link phone to tablet, and the phone keeps dying,  and the sprint store says it can't save my calendar to a new phone becuz its not a goggle calendar.and i cant charge the phone to access the calendar. I need to access and download my calendar at least, even if i cant save it to my new phone. ideas?

Comment: Unless that calendar is stored on the SD card and you can access it that way, you're out of luck unless you can charge your phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you can turn the phone on, set jorte to sync with a google calendar. Then you can get it on any android device you want.

If the phone is dead and you can't charge it you may try charging the battery with an external charger then following the step above.